# How to use vue-select in a simple HTML page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

It is my first "try" with Vue + vue-select.

I have imported Vue and vue-select like it is explained in the vue-select [documentation](https://vue-select.org/guide/install.html#in-the-browser).

And my first try is this simple HTML page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- include VueJS first -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>

    <!-- use the latest vue-select release -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest/dist/vue-select.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Vue Select</h1>
      <v-select :options="options"></v-select>
    </div>

    <script>
      Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect.VueSelect);

      new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try this page, I have these errors in the console :

[image]

What it is wrong in this first try? When I understand this first example, it will be easier for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked your code and seems this issue is due to the `vue` version you are using. I just used version `2.*` and it is working.

Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect.VueSelect);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: 'foo',
    options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-select/3.10.3/vue-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select/dist/vue-select.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <v-select :options="options" v-model="selected"></v-select>
</div>
```

Update **:** Here is the Vue 3 version of `v-select`

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
  }),
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@3.0.0-next-20220604.0/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@3.0.0-next-20220604.0/dist/vuetify.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-select
            :items="items"
          ></v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, and yes it works with the version 2.*   , it means that this componet is perhaps not the ideal if I want to start with vue 3.

Comment: @Dom I updated my answer with the Vue 3 version of v-select as well. You can use any one of the solution as per your requirement.